# Looking for a visualization and charting package

Tags: canvas, data-visualization, google-visualization

I have some specific requirements, with the most important at the top:

- Can plot line and stacked bar charts
- Can customize mouse events (hover, click) on chart data
- Compatible and performant with IE7/8  (likely will use [excanvas.js](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/))
- Can optionally control label formats, legends, colors
- Open source preferred, or at least can purchase the source
- Can be hosted locally

I have seen a couple potentially good ones:

- Google's [interactive charts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/) (But code must be accessed via Google servers)
- [EJSChart](http://www.ejschart.com/)
- [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

Does anyone have experience with these, or others, and can make a recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used www.anychart.com/home
in our recent project.
It is based on flash but you can easily work with it via generating xml.

But one very big problem - generate image from flash is very difficult.

Also i know that MS have their charts(free) - code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: Also http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/ but i haven't worked with it and can't sat will it satisfy your requirements or not

Answer (score 0):

Another one to take a look at is the [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) JavaScript library which is an extension of [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). This is a popular graphical toolkit for JavaScript and is open-source.